# Force parsing a from parent-type to child-type?

Tags: java, android, casting

I have a class that have many other classes extends it. So now I use GenericPool to recycle items for better performance. But the problem is, I can't cast child class, for example:

```
StarDustSprite sprStarDust = (StarDustSprite) splStarDust[rndGenerator.nextInt(Parent.andStarDustR.length)].obtainPoolItem();
```

(StarDustSprite extends a class named Sprite, and the obtainPoolItem() function return a Sprite object).

So can I force parse it? Or I have to make 10 GenericPool class if I have 10 child-classes?

Thank you.

Comment: Beware - recycling objects "for better performance" can lead to *worse* performance!

Comment: Could you explain why? Everytime I create a Sprite, I have to create a Texture and a TextureRegion, as well as init the Sprite (I mean the class that extends Sprite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **So can I force parse it?**

No, you can't cast like that, for the same reason as you can't cast for example an `Object` into a `String`.

> **Or I have to make 10 GenericPool class if I have 10 child-classes?**

I guess so. But I wouldn't solve it like this in the first place.

If you really want to reuse objects, I suggest you just lazily initialize a list of objects, which you can later reuse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't initialize that list, because I don't know exactly how many I would need. But there're a lot of child class, so I hope there's a better solution!

Comment: That's why you would do it lazily, i.e., "on-demand". Look up lazy initialization.

Comment: OK, thank you, look like copy GenericPool class is simplier, because I only have to change the class type name. Problem solved!